# How to develop background task in windows phone runtime app 8.1 when app is closed?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I want to develop background task when app is closed.I searched on google but I am not getting any proper answer.I am developing windows phone runtime app,not silver light.please help me..

Answer (score 1):

you can develop now  - `UWP apps`

learn UWP - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop

Windows 8 development -https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt244353.aspx

Support your app with background tasks- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks

Get started with Windows apps - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getstarted

Answer (score 0):

Creating background Task is easy.
You can go through this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task